# How can i pass the values of the texformfield to a list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textformfield

Hi I have an address page where i am taking details of the user. There is a form also all the neccessary validations are provided I want to take all the details that are provided by the user and store it in a list so that i can use that list and store it in database. But whenever i am trying to add those elements to the list and printing the same the list displays null.

This is my code.

```
  TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(

                  hintText: 'Enter your Name'),
              maxLength: 20,
              validator: (String value) {
                address.clear();
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Name is Required';
                }

                return null;
              },

              onSaved: (String value) {
                _name = value;
                address.add(value);



              },
          ),
RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text('Proceed to order',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
              onPressed: (){
                if(_formKey.currentState.validate()) {

                  print("address" + address.toString());
                  switch(widget.font) {

                    case'a': {

                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Onlinepage()));
                      /*Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Onlinepage()));*/

                    }
                    break;

                    case 'b': {

                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Codpage(address:address,orderListFinal:widget.orderListFinal,total:widget.total)));



                    }
                    break;
```

This is the output
I/flutter (19488): address[]
and below is the whole code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

import 'package:kartofill/Homepagewithprice/Codpage.dart';
import 'package:kartofill/Homepagewithprice/Onlinepage.dart';


var address = [];

class Deliveryaddresspage extends StatefulWidget {

  var total;
  List orderListFinal = [];
  var font;



  Deliveryaddresspage({this.font, this.orderListFinal, this.total});

  @override
  _DeliveryaddresspageState createState() => _DeliveryaddresspageState();
}

class _DeliveryaddresspageState extends State<Deliveryaddresspage> {
  String _name;
  String _pincode;
  String _address1;
  String _address2;
  String _address3;
  String _phoneNumber;


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

  }
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(

            child: RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text('Proceed to order',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
              onPressed: (){
                if(_formKey.currentState.validate()) {

                  print("address" + address.toString());
                  switch(widget.font) {

                    case'a': {

                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Onlinepage()));
                      /*Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Onlinepage()));*/

                    }
                    break;

                    case 'b': {

                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Codpage(address:address,orderListFinal:widget.orderListFinal,total:widget.total)));



                    }
                    break;



                    default: {
                      Fluttertoast
                          .showToast(
                          msg: "Please Select any one of the above options",
                          toastLength: Toast
                              .LENGTH_SHORT,
                          gravity: ToastGravity
                              .CENTER,
                          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                          backgroundColor: Colors
                              .red,
                          textColor: Colors
                              .white,
                          fontSize: 16.0
                      );
                    }
                    break;
                  }
                }


              },

            ),
          )
        ],

      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('KartOfill'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[

                  Center(child: Text('Delivery Address',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25),)),
                  SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.001,),
          TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(

                  hintText: 'Enter your Name'),
              maxLength: 20,
              validator: (String value) {
                address.clear();
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Name is Required';
                }

                return null;
              },

              onSaved: (String value) {
                _name = value;
                address.add(value);



              },
          ),

                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter 10 digit phone Number'),
                    maxLength: 10,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      new BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(
                          new RegExp(
                              '[\\.|\\,|\\-|\\ ]'))
                    ],
                    validator: (String value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Phone number is Required';
                      }

                      if( value.length < 10 || !RegExp(r'^[0-9]+$').hasMatch(value))
                      {

                        return 'Please enter correct 10 digit phone number';
                      }

                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (String value) {
                      _phoneNumber = value;

                    },
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Address 1'),
                    maxLength: 20,
                    validator: (String value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Address is Required';
                      }

                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (String value) {
                      _address1 = value;


                    },
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Address 2'),
                    maxLength: 20,

                    onSaved: (String value) {
                      _address2 = value;

                    },
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Address 3'),
                    maxLength: 20,

                    onSaved: (String value) {
                      _address3 = value;

                    },
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Pincode'),
                    maxLength: 6,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      new BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(
                          new RegExp(
                              '[\\.|\\,|\\-|\\ ]'))
                    ],
                    validator: (String value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty  ) {
                        return 'Pincode is Required';
                      }
                      else if (value.length < 6 || !RegExp(r'^[0-9]+$').hasMatch(value)){

                        return 'Please enter correct pincode';
                      }

                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (String value) {
                      _pincode = value;

                    },
                  ),



                ],
              ),
            ),

          ),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `onChanged:(){}` instead of using onSaved

Comment: But i am unable to add those fields in a list .. For example  validator: (String value) {
                address.clear();
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Name is Required';
                }

                return null;
              },

              onChanged: (String value) {

                setState(() {
                  _name = value;
                  address.add(_name);
                });